# How can I keep on logging after retirement of instrumentationkey and classic application insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I am confused. As clearly published by Microsoft, [Classic Application Insights is retired as of today](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/we-re-retiring-classic-application-insights-on-29-february-2024/).

That is unfortunate but not the end of the world. There is an alternative: log analytics workspace. So how to do my logging now? Well, I found an answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1157487/how-to-log-data-to-azure-log-analytics-workspace-f).

However, this alternative approach relies on the well-known instrumentation key. This is going to be [retired in approximately a year](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/778615/retirement-announcement-technical-support-for-inst). So that is not very future proof, is it?

So how should I do my logging to (to log analytics workspace) without relying on deprecated NuGet packages, deprecated technologies or "retirement announced" technology?

Please just give me a C# example of how to do this nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

> So how should I do my logging to (to log analytics workspace) without relying on deprecated NuGet packages, deprecated technologies or "retirement announced" technology?

Just make sure you use an up to date version of the [AI Skd](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore). Then, connect to your workspace based Application Insights resource using the connection string instead of the instrumentation key. It is al explained in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcorenew%2Cnetcore6#enable-application-insights-server-side-telemetry-no-visual-studio):

Put the connection string in the app settings:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "Copy connection string from Application Insights Resource Overview"
  }
}
```

and inject the SDK:

```cs
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// The following line enables Application Insights telemetry collection.
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

// This code adds other services for your application.
builder.Services.AddMvc();

var app = builder.Build();
```

We have migrated some classic AI resources to workspace based AI resources. It didn't cause much trouble as we just had to change the InstrumentationKey to the ConnectionString in the settings file or update our code to set the connection string instead of the instrumentation key:

```cs
 services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options =>
 {
     options.ConnectionString = "InstrumentationKey=xxx;IngestionEndpoint=https://westeurope-5.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://westeurope.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/";
 });
```

There is not much to it really.

If you still have AI resources that have to be updated go to that resource, click the warning message and follow the steps. No changes have to be done to the configuration of the applications sending telemetry when it comes to moving away from the classic to the workspace based resources:

[image]

or visit the [docs regarding the migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource).

Comment: You're still using the InstrumentationKey (as part of the connectionstring)

Comment: @Daan yes , but that is not going away. But as soon as you set the instrument key instead of the connection string using the SDK you will get a deprecated warning.

Comment: My guess is this: previous, using only the instrumentation keys all telemetry was send to the same fixed endpoint. Using the connection string, which is a combination of the instrumentation key and an endpoint, the SDK can route the telemetry to different endpoints. I can imagening that app insights resources in the USA route telemetry to other endpoints than resources in Europe for example.

Comment: You assume that a migration was done. https://chat.openai.com/share/8029881d-68bd-499f-8979-243c198a5961

Comment: @Daan Correct. The migration can be done using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource). It is pretty straightforward and doesn't mean your application needs modification.

Comment: How would do it in general (so including newly created log analytics workspace). Companies that started  today do not need to do any migration of legacy resources.